# Removing space on the right side

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding

I am working on a SharePoint online site where I removed the navigation, top bar etc using script editor and CSS, and added my own HTML page. However I there is a space between the page and the right scroll bar (as shown in the image below).

How do I remove it ?

[image]

Comment: Have you fixed width of HTML content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSS on page

```
    #contentBox {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
    }
    #contentBox table table {
        padding: 5px 0px 10px 10px !important;
    }
```

Comment: there is still a tiny bit more space in the left. updated the image in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[using `!important` in CSS should be done with care](https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/)

```
#contentBox{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0
}
```

Will cover the whole viewport;